# django "a contains b" on ManyToManyField between A and B

Tags: django, orm

I have two tables `A` and `B`. `A.bs` is a `ManyToManyField` onto `B`.

I want to fetch all `a` in  `A` where `a.bs` contains a certain `b` from `B`.

The only way I know how to do it is like this:

```
def get_all_A_containing_b(b):
    return filter(lambda a: b in a.bs, A.objects.all())
```

I'd prefer to have this all done by the DBMS, but I don't want to write any SQL code or use django internals.

The SQL would look something like this: (I can't remember the semantics of JOIN and nulls so this may be wrong)

```
SELECT * FROM A a
LEFT JOIN A2B a2b on a2b.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN B b on a2b.b_id = b.id
WHERE b.id = $b;
```

where `$b` is replaced with the `id` of the `b` from `B` I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the reverse lookup through one of the automatic _set attributes?

```
b = B.objects.get( b_id)
a_list = b.a_set.all()
```

I am answering from my mobile so I can't test if this works.

-Justin

Comment: ehhhhh, you are right, but only because I didn't provide enough context in my question, I'll post again if I remember why this doesn't work :)

Answer (score 4):

whats the problem with
    `as = A.objects.filter(bs=b)`?

Comment: because it's comparing a set against a scalar? actually I remember seeing some code like this before, but thought it was a bug, so maybe you're right and it's some django shortcut

Comment: well it should do what you're asking for... remember that it could make sense to put a `distinct()` at the end, as you more than one relation from an `A` object may point to a `B` object... and you should also be able to do it with a list as well: `A.objects.filter(bs__in=[b]). http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/

Comment: ye this works, thanks for pointing me to doc, I was looking for that. Strangely, this even works on another table `C` with one `OneToOneField` onto `B`, ie: `A.objects.filter(bs__in=[C.objects.get(id=9000)])`